# Publish ASP.NET Core to Azure fails unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, asp.net-core, web-deployment

I have a project based on ASP.NET Core 1.0. I can build and run locally without any problems, but if I try to publish the project to Azure using the publish mechanism in Visual Studio 2015 (even if I try to publish locally to a folder in file system or using FTP) it fails unexpectedly without giving me any concrete message. If I run preview I always get this log:

```
    The "Publish" task failed unexpectedly.
    System.Exception: 
    Publishing Project.Web for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2/win7-x64

   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tasks.Publish.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

If I try to publish ignoring this error or if I do not try to get the preview I get this:

```
1>------ Publish started: Project: Kunato.Web, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
rmdir /S /Q "C:\Users\thimo\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\Kunato.Web54\"
Environment variables:
DOTNET_CONFIGURE_AZURE=1
Path=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish "C:\Code\Git\Web_KuNaTo\src\Kunato.Web" --framework net452 --output "C:\Users\thimo\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\Kunato.Web54" --configuration Debug --no-build
Publishing Kunato.Web for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2/win7-x64

1>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 7 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I the do as requested and look at the error list, there is no error and everything looks good. Are there any other log files or anything to check where the problem might be?

project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-Kunato.Web-753ff034-0ada-4809-84a8-a4f157c4ea43",

  "dependencies": {
    "Kunato.Common": "1.0.0-*",
    "Kunato.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Kunato.DataAccess": "1.0.0-*",
    "Kunato.Edi": "1.0.0-*",
    "Kunato.Entities": "1.0.0-*",
    "Kunato.Localization": "1.0.0-*",
    "ediFabric.Framework": "6.7.0",
    "LumenWorksCsvReader": "3.9.0",
    "Sendgrid": "6.3.4",
    "StackExchange.Redis": "1.1.0-alpha2",
    "StackExchange.Redis.StrongName": "1.1.0-alpha2",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Kunato.Web.Services;
using Kunato.DataAccess;
using Kunato.Entities.Core;
using Kunato.Web.Helpers;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Kunato.DataAccess.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace Kunato.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets();

                // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add Application Insights data collection services to the services container.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<KunatoDatabaseContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Kunato.Web")));

            services.AddIdentity<KunatoUser, KunatoRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@-.";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<KunatoDatabaseContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            // Add session
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.CookieName = ".kunato.Session";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            });

            // Add localization
            services.AddLocalization();

            // Register Version service
            services.AddSingleton<IDeploymentEnvironment, DeploymentEnvironment>();

            // Add localization to the request pipeline
            var dtf = new DateTimeFormatInfo
            {
                ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy",
                LongDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
                ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm",
                LongTimePattern = "HH:mm"
            };
            var nf = new NumberFormatInfo
            {
                CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",",
                CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".",
                NumberDecimalSeparator = ",",
                NumberGroupSeparator = ".",
                NumberDecimalDigits = 3
            };

            // Add MVC services to the services container.
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    // handle loops correctly
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                        Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

                    // use standard name conversion of properties
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

                    // include $id property in the output
                    options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
                        PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
                })
                .AddViewLocalization()
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            // Register Filters
            services.AddScoped<LanguageActionFilter>();

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                options =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                        {
                            //new CultureInfo("en-US") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
                            //new CultureInfo("en") { DateTimeFormat = dtf },
                            new CultureInfo("de-DE") { DateTimeFormat = dtf, NumberFormat = nf },
                            new CultureInfo("de") { DateTimeFormat = dtf, NumberFormat = nf }
                            //new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                            //new CultureInfo("en"),
                            //new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                            //new CultureInfo("de")
                        };

                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "de-DE", uiCulture: "de-DE");
                    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                });


            // Add application settings from config
            services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

            // Register KunatoBaseData
            //services.AddTransient<KunatoBaseData>();
            //services.AddTransient<KunatoSampleData>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            // Add Application Insights to the request pipeline to track HTTP request telemetry data.
            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            // For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
            try
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<KunatoDatabaseContext>().Database.Migrate();

                    // Seeding the basic data to the database
                    var kunatoBaseData = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<KunatoBaseData>();
                    await kunatoBaseData.InitializeDataAsync();

                    // Seeding sample data to the database
                    //var kunatoSampleData = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<KunatoSampleData>();
                    //await kunatoSampleData.InitializeDataAsync();
                }
            }
            catch { }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();

            // Add session
            app.UseSession();

            // Add localization
            var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `project.json` and `Startup.cs` files of your application?

Comment: I edited my question with both files. Thank you!

Comment: Everything seems fine. For getting debug information in production, Go to Azure App settings and add the following property there with name `ASPNET_ENV` with value `Development` and see what is the problem in production.

Comment: Can you manually run the command `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish "C:\Code\Git\Web_KuNaTo\src\Kunato.Web" --framework net452 --output "C:\Users\thimo\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\Kunato.Web54" --configuration Debug --no-build
` from command line, but make sure to put a `-v` before `publish` to enable verbose output to see any additional details

Comment: I ran the command as you wrote it and it perfectly ran without any issues. So this way works for publish to my local filesystem. I also tried to do it with a Release configuration which also worked. But I afterwards tried it again from Visual Studio and the problem is still there as initially described...